# InputField can't be used with a commandButton that use rerender

Tags: visualforce, attachment, rerender, commandbutton, apexinputfile

*apex:inputFile can not be used in conjunction with an action component, apex:commandButton or apex:commandLink that specifies a rerender or oncomplete attribute.*

This is the message I get when I press one of the commandButton that use rerender on my VF page to add a Attachment to my wrapper.

What I want to do is be able to add a related file to the records present on my page. I will add them by flling the ownedId field on my Attachement variable when all the records are inserted.

I know that the problem is that an inputFile can't be used while there is a commandButton or a commandlink that are rerendering the form.

And I know that a workaroud is to wrap the commandButtons in a actionRegion, but it doesn't seems to work, it just doesn't do the rerender anymore, so i'm not able to see the objects I just added or removed.

Here is my VF page. Is there something I can try to change to make it work?

```
<apex:page standardController="ProductRequest" recordSetVar="ProductRequest" extensions="ProductRequestController2" tabstyle="Project__c">
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="Edit Products Requests">
        <apex:repeat value="{!fieldSetsKeys}" var="fieldSetKey"> 
            <apex:variable var="name" value="{!fieldSetKey}"/>
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="{!name}" columns="1">
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!wrappers[name]}" var="wrapper"  id="Table">
                    
                    <apex:column headerValue="#">   <apex:outputText value="{!wrapper.ident}"/> </apex:column>
                    
                    <apex:repeat value="{!fieldSets[fieldSetKey]}" var="field">
                        <apex:column headerValue="{!field}">
                            <apex:inputField value="{!wrapper.product[field]}" />
                        </apex:column>
                    </apex:repeat>
                    
                    <apex:column headerValue="Insert file">
                        <apex:inputFile value="{!wrapper.file.Body}"/>
                    </apex:column>
                    
                    
                    <apex:column headerValue="Action on row">
                        <apex:actionRegion renderRegionOnly="false">
                            <apex:commandButton value="Clone" action="{!copyRow}" rerender="Table">
                                <apex:param name="selectedRow" value="{!wrapper.ident}" assignTo="{!selectedRow}"/>
                                <apex:param name="productType" value="{!name}" assignTo="{!productType}"/>
                            </apex:commandButton>
                            <apex:commandButton value="Delete" action="{!deleteRow}" rerender="Table">
                                <apex:param name="selectedRow" value="{!wrapper.ident}" assignTo="{!selectedRow}"/>
                                <apex:param name="productType" value="{!name}" assignTo="{!productType}"/>
                            </apex:commandButton>
                        </apex:actionRegion>
                    </apex:column>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
                
                <apex:outputPanel >
                    <apex:actionRegion renderRegionOnly="false">
                        <apex:commandButton value="Add Row" action="{!addRows}" rerender="Table">
                            <apex:param name="addCount" value="1" assignTo="{!addCount}"/>
                            <apex:param name="productType" value="{!name}" assignTo="{!productType}"/>
                        </apex:commandButton>
                        <apex:commandButton value="Add 5 Rows" action="{!addRows}" rerender="Table">
                            <apex:param name="addCount" value="5" assignTo="{!addCount}"/>
                            <apex:param name="productType" value="{!name}" assignTo="{!productType}"/>
                        </apex:commandButton>
                    </apex:actionRegion>
                </apex:outputPanel>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:repeat>
        
        
        <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
            <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

</apex:page>

[image]

Comment: Did you use renderRegionOnly="false" on the Apex:actionRegion? That usually fixes the problem.

Comment: Yes, I tried renderRegionOnly="false", but I dont see any difference. I use it to wrap all what is in the action on row column and output panel. Am I doing it the wrong way?